# Passing ImageView into a constructor

Tags: android

From my main activity, I would like to pass a `ImageView` to the constructor of another class, or the object of this class if you like. Some codesnippets beneath.

**The class case:**

```
public class Case {

String id; 
int status; 
Date date;
ImageView orginalFace;
ImageView profilePicture; 


public Case(String id, int status, Date date, ImageView orginalFace, ImageView profilePicture) {

    this.id= id;
    this.status = status;
    this.date = date;
    this.orginalFace= orginalFace;
    this.profilePicture= profilePicture; 

  }
}
```

**And this is where I try to add an ImageView:**

```
ArrayList<Case> cases = new ArrayList<Case>(); 

    Case case1 = new Case("991176565809", 1, new Date(), R.drawable.face, R.drawable.profile);
```

I am aware of that when I try to add `R.drawable.face` and `R.drawable.profile` this is just `integers`. How can i manage to do this correctly?

Comment: Actually what you want to achieve by doing this?

Comment: This is just for test purposes. Actually the images are supposed to come from a webservice.

Comment: Its depends on your actual requirement, If image comes from WebService then it better to use Bitmap instead of ImageView.

Comment: I haven't decided yet how I should implement this. But got the answer for my test purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can load the two ImageViews like this:

```
ImageView faceImg = new ImageView(context);
faceImg.setImageResource(R.drawable.face);

ImageView profileImg = new ImageView(context);
profileImg.setImageResource(R.drawable.profile);
```

Answer (score 1):

To pass your `ImageView` you can use the `findViewById(int id)` method. In your case:

```
ArrayList<Case> cases = new ArrayList<Case>(); 

ImageView imageView1 = new ImageView(yourActivitysContext);
imageView1.setImageResource(R.drawable.face);

ImageView imageView2 = new ImageView(yourActivitysContext);
imageView2.setImageResource(R.drawable.profile);

Case case1 = new Case("991176565809", 1, new Date(), imageView1 , imageView2 );
```

However i must warn you that storing your imageViews in the memory is not a good practice.